# Google Drive API List files filter file is owner = true not work

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I make Android app and using Google Drive API, I want to get list files that has "ownedByMe = true". But it does not work ? That is my code:

```
var request = drive.files().list()
                    .setSpaces("drive")
                    .setFields("nextPageToken,files(id,name,mimeType,modifiedTime,createdTime,fileExtension,size,parents,kind" +
                            ",webContentLink,thumbnailLink,contentHints(thumbnail),trashed,ownedByMe)")
                    .setPageSize(100)
                    .setQ("ownedByMe='true'")
                    .setPageToken(afterCur)
                    .execute()
```

Comment: Q is very limited in what it can search for https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms#drive_properties

Comment: how can I filter with ownedByMe='true' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .setQ("ownedByMe='true'")

Is not an option for searching with [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms#drive_properties)  it is in fact very limited.

You should try using

```
'me' in owners
```

Comment: How can I find style query google drive ? 
I do not know why we use "'me' in owners" but not "ownedByMe='true'"